# Computational example: Using the zeroth homology group to find the number of path components

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, path-connected

I'm studying singular homology, and I have a question about $H_0 (X)$, the zeroth homology group of a space $X$.

I understand that the Betti number of $H_0 (X)$ equals the number of the path components of $X$.

But my question is: is this information useful to compute the number of path components of $X$? If so, then can you give me a *computational example*? It makes me reluctant to use $H_0(X)$ to find just the number of path components of $X$. The answer would be great if using $H_0(X)$ is a must or the easiest way.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually it won't be, but there are exceptions, usually involving duality. For example, the Jordan curve theorem stating that a codimension one embedded sphere separates the plane into two pieces is easiest proved by Alexander duality for dimension 0 homology. A different flavor of example might come from working in a more algebraic flavor of spaces, such as spectra or topological groups, then there can be nontrivial calculations involving 0th homology.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality . The important thing to note when working with 0th homology is that almost never is it degenerate, i.e. if something works for dimension n homology, it almost always works for 0th homology as well. This means that algebraic arguments work just as well even though it seems a little weird.

Comment: We usually go the other way:  use the number of path components to compute the zeroth homology.

Comment: Maybe not directly relevant, but if you only know $X$ via finite samples, i.e., as a point cloud, then it may not be so clear what the number of components is (or means). *Persistent* homology of the point cloud in dimension 0 "recovers" the number of components of $X$.  (In this case, persistent $H_0$ is just a fancy way of saying clustering, typically single-linkage clustering.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact $H_0(X)$ is a free abelian group whose rank (= Betti number) equals the number of the path components of $X$. But there is no way to compute $H_0(X)$ without *previously determining* the number of the path components of $X$.

Thus the number of path components of $X$ is needed to compute $H_0(X)$, but not conversely.

Comment: I mean, when was the last time you computed *any* of the $H^i$ directly in the singular theory? While one typically already knows the number of path components in a given situation, the computation of $H^0$ *can* be done from a $\Delta$-complex or CW-complex structure. Or am I misunderstanding your perspective here?

Comment: @TabesBridges Of course it does not make much sense to compute $H_n(X)$ directly, except in trivial cases or for $n = 0$. You are certainly right that you can compute $H_0(X)$ of a CW-complex as a quotient of the free abelian group generated by the $0$-cells, but to do so you need the incidence relations between $1$-cells and $0$-cells. Having this information is IMO much more than knowing the number of path components. And if you have infinitely many $0$-cells, it seems that determining the quotient group by collecting infinitely many incidence relations is only a theoretical approach.

Comment: Oh yes, certainly in any situation in which one can compute $H_0$, one is strictly compressing information.